# jQuery $.post causes browser stack overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, stack-overflow, .post

I have the following jQuery code:

```
var id_atual
var temp_id
var tempo_flash = 50
var $slide_atual = $('#slider .atual')
var $slide_prox = $('#slider .ocultar')
setInterval(function(){
    id_atual = $slide_atual.attr('alt')
    $.post('get_banner.php', {atual: id_atual}, function(proximo){
        temp_id = proximo.split(';;')
        $slide_prox.attr('src', temp_id[0]).load(function(){
            $slide_atual.hide('fade', tempo_flash, function(){
                $slide_atual.attr('alt', temp_id[1]).attr('src', temp_id[0]).load(function(){
                    $slide_atual.show('fade', tempo_flash)
                })
            })
        })
    })
}, 4000)
```

And the following HTML code:

```
<div id="slider">
    <img src="imagens/slider/imagen-slider.jpg" alt="1" class="atual"/>
    <img src="" alt="" class="ocultar" />
</div>
```

Where the class .ocultar have a

```
display: none;
```

The vars tempo_flash is only the animation time, and the file get_banner.php is only for getting the next banner from the mysql database. It is tested and working fine.
The problem I have is that after a little (4 or 5 banner changing) the browser stops answering (for Firefox Chrome and Opera) and on IE I get an alert `Stack overflow at line: 3` and the javascript of the whole page stops working.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: You should spend the money to get that semicolon key fixed :-)

Comment: Try changing your `$.post()` to `$.ajax()` and including a `timeout` parameter. I'd imagine that the AJAX requests are taking some time to complete and stacking up and therefore eating the browsers resources.

Comment: I think part of the problem might be that you declare all those variables *outside* the function. There's no reason for that; they should be declared *inside* the function passed to `setInterval()`. As it is, it's very likely that the separate functions are stepping on eachother's toes.

Comment: i tried to put the var declarations inside, and got the same error... i'm trying to changing to $.ajax right now, but the firebug says it's getting less than 200ms every post...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside each iteration of the setInterval()ed function, you assign a `.load()` event to an image place holder. Assigning an event to an object **does not remove existing ones**!

So on second iteration, the image place holder will have two `.load()` event handlers, then three and so on; and every time the image is loaded, it will fire all event handlers attached to `.load()` event. You probably need to re-factor your code, perhaps by assigning the `.load()` event handler only once (and use semicolons).

Comment: Took off all theh .load() events, and it stops giving the "stack overflow" error, so its solved!!!!! thank you Salman, is there a better way to trigger an event only when the image finnish loading, after changing the "src"?

Comment: Attach `.load()` event to the element so it will fire whenever the image finishes loading. Inside the callback function you can check `$(this).attr("src")` to check which image was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use setInterval, you should use a setTimeout inside a function, and execute it on the callback of the $.post, something like:

```
var id_atual
var temp_id
var tempo_flash = 50
var $slide_atual = $('#slider .atual')
var $slide_prox = $('#slider .ocultar')
function tictac(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        id_atual = $slide_atual.attr('alt')
        $.post('get_banner.php', {atual: id_atual}, function(proximo){
            temp_id = proximo.split(';;')
            $slide_prox.attr('src', temp_id[0]).load(function(){
                $slide_atual.hide('fade', tempo_flash, function(){
                    $slide_atual.attr('alt', temp_id[1]).attr('src', temp_id[0]).load(function(){
                        $slide_atual.show('fade', tempo_flash)
                    })
                })
            })
        })
        ticktac();
    }, 4000);
}
```

this way, the 4 seconds only start counting if and when the response from the server is complete, you will not have your overflow problems

Comment: i've just tried this and got the same error...
its running on tarcisiofotografia.com.br/site

Comment: i´ve tried to use the recursivity outside the setTimeout, like
setTimeout(function(){
...
},4000);
tictac()
and nothing...

Comment: If you went to the trouble to rewrite, why not include the semicolons? ;)